# Fourier transform of $\cos(a |x| + \theta )$

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Here $a \neq 0 $. Both $a$ and $\theta $ are real numbers.

I tried to consider its Fourier transform and therefore considered the integral

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ik x } \cos(a|x| + \theta ) dx . $$

The problem is that the integral does not converge. I then tried to regularize it by introducing the factor $e^{-\lambda |x|}$, where $\lambda $ is a positive number which will be taken to $0$ in the end.

By simple and straightforward calculation, I get

$$ \cos \theta \left ( \frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2 + (k-a)^2} + \frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2 + (k+a)^2} \right )+\sin \theta \left(  \frac{k-a}{\lambda^2 + (k-a)^2} + \frac{k+a }{\lambda^2 + (k+a)^2}  \right). $$

Letting $\lambda \rightarrow 0^+$, I get

$$ \pi \cos \theta  (\delta(k-a) + \delta(k+a))+ \sin\theta \left (\frac{P}{k-a} - \frac{P}{k+a} \right). $$

Here $P$ means the principal value.

Is this right?

It should be related to the theory of distribution, right?

Comment: $f_\lambda(x)=e^{-\lambda |x|} \cos(a|x|+\theta) \to f(x)=\cos(a|x|+\theta)$ in the sense of tempered distributions so $\hat{f_\lambda} \to \hat{f}$ in the sense of tempered distributions  which is what you got. To be sure I like to express $\frac{1}{k-a+i\lambda}$ as the derivative of $\log(k-a+i\lambda)$ which $\to \log|k-a| + i \pi 1_{k-a < 0}$ whose distributional derivative is $-i \pi \delta(k-a)+pv(\frac{1}{k-a})$

Comment: The last term in the second formula should be $-(k + a)/(\lambda^2 + (k + a)^2)$. The final result is correct. Since $e^{i a |x|} = e^{i a x} H(x) + e^{-i a x} H(-x)$, you can just compute $\mathcal F[H]$.